# Fazer sort de uma lista

Tags: c#, classificação

Estou a tentar fazer um sort de uma lista que tem informações de um ficheiro de texto, para ir buscar as informações ao ficheiro eu uso:

```
string ficheiro = "tvInfo.txt";
List<string> Classificacoes;
var linha = File.ReadAllLines(ficheiro);
Classificacoes = new List<string>();

foreach (var linhas in linha)
{
    Classificacoes.Add(linhas);
}
```

Após ir buscar as informações a lista fica assim:

```
Liverpool;50
Arsenal;10
Benfica;20
PSG;30
```

Eu queria fazer o sort da lista a partir do segundo campo.
Estou a tentar usar o Linq mas não consigo passar daqui:

```
Classificacoes.OrderByDescending(c => c);
```

Comment: É bem simples, você fez algum código?

Comment: O código que eu tenho é so para preencher a lista com as informações do ficheiro de texto string ficheiro = "tvInfo.txt";
            List<string> Classificacoes;
            var linha = File.ReadAllLines(ficheiro);
            Classificacoes = new List<string>();

            foreach (var linhas in linha)
            {
                Classificacoes.Add(linhas);
            }

Comment: Então essa lista é só utilizar Linq com o método OrderBy que resolve

Comment: Isso é o que eu tenho estado a tentar fazer Classificacoes.OrderByDescending(c=>c), mas o problema é que eu não consigo completar o código

Comment: Você precisa colocar isso na sua pergunta e organizar melhor o seu código esse texto precisa ainda ser quebrado em duas partes cada linha

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá.

Primeiramente você precisa ordenar a lista a partir do nome ou da pontuação?

Se for a partir do nome, é tranquilo. Só usar o `Linq` Dessa forma:

```
Classificacoes = Classificacoes.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToList();
```

Isso porque o `OrderByDescending` te retorna um objeto, entao nao adianta tu colocar ele no vazio ali.

Agora, se tu precisar ordenar pelo numero, te recomendo usar um `dicionario`

```
Dictionary<string, int>()
```

aonde o nome do teu time é a key, e o numero é a pontuacao, dessa forma você pode usar o `Linq` igualmente, só que agora, ordenando por valor:

```
Classificacoes = Classificacoes.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).ToList();
```